# function inputs in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

So i have started using classes in python and i am still learning how it works. so in this part of my code and i found something that i don't understand.

```
def Button(self):
        self.Button = QPushButton("Push me Bitch!",self)
        self.Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 500, 5, 5))
        self.Button.resize(self.Button.minimumSizeHint())
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonPress(someInput))


    # Do functions
    def ButtonPress(self , someInput):
         print('someInput')
         self.OutputBox1.setText('I Has Been Pressed!')
```

And this is the error that i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python shizzle\BijHillen\BijGui.py", line 92, in <module>
    ex = Example()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python shizzle\BijHillen\BijGui.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.Button()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python shizzle\BijHillen\BijGui.py", line 68, in Button
    self.Button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonPress(5))
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python shizzle\BijHillen\BijGui.py", line 74, in ButtonPress
    self.OutputBox1.setText('I Have Been Pressed!!!')
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'OutputBox1'
```

If i remove the someInput. Then there is no problem. How does this work?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your event setup is wrong, when you attach an event to a button you generally want to link the function, not the *result* of the function to the `clicked` event.

Instead of:

```
self.Button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonPress(someInput))
```

You want:

```
self.Button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonPress)
```

That way the function will get called when the button is clicked.

You might have some other issues with your code, but start by fixing that.